# Generate multiple stylesheets to gulp

Tags: variables, less, rename, gulp, multitasking

I want to run a task gulp generating multiple stylesheets less. all are equal only changes one of theimport containing values of different variables.

```
| -- src/
     | -- less/
          | -- colors/
               |-- blue.less
               |-- red.less
          | -- main.less
| -- dist/
     | -- css/
          | -- blue.css
          | -- red.css
```

The **main.less** file looks like this:

```
@import <color>

/* more code... */
```

Where  should be replaced by: **red.less**, **blue.less**...

Once the corresponding import made should generate the css files: **red.css**, **blue.css**...

Answer (score 2):

I used a loop, but not if it is the best solution:

```js
gulp.task('less', function() {
    for (var color in data.colors) {
        gulp.src(['src/less/colors/' + data.colors[color] + '.less', 'src/less/reason.less'])
        .pipe(concat('style-' + data.colors[color] + '.less'))
        .pipe(less({
            paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'less')],
            plugins: [autoprefix, cleancss]
            
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path_css));
    }
});
```